# Is there any method to count an average date time in python and visualize it?

Tags: python, csv, datetime

I am new in python. This is my `datetime`. I have it in `csv`. Here I have two columns `Call` and `Time`.

```
                        Time;"Call"
0         2019-12-10 11:35:55;"Answer"
1         2019-12-10 11:31:42;"Not Answer"
2      2019-12-10 11:26:42;"Answer"
3      2019-12-10 11:23:24;"Answer"
4      2019-12-10 11:22:28;"Answer"
5      2019-12-10 11:21:31;"Not Answer"
6         2019-12-10 11:02:08;"Answer"
```

How can I count the average `datetime` so I will know when is the best time to call ?

Comment: I don't think an average is a correct way to solve this problem. If you're having trouble with a piece of code, please include it (along with expected inputs/outputs) so we can help

Answer (score 0):

Average is probably not the way to go here. You may want to get day of the week and hour from each time and then you can try visualizing heatmap of average response rate.

Comment: okay I got it, but is it possible to do another thing. To create a graph in x date for y numbers